# How to do this gradual hover effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

Heres a link: http://www.45royale.com/work/

On his page when you hover over a work he has done a cool hover comes over it. It replace the image with another.  Is this jquery or css? How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery along with two separate images, fading in and out on hover.

You should learn to use the view source/developer tools probably built in to your browser (try hitting F12).

Here's the relevant code:

```
$("div.casestudy img.hovered").hide();
$("div.casestudy").hover(function() {
$(this).find('img').fadeIn(200);
}, function() {
$(this).find('img.hovered').fadeOut(200);
});
```

http://www.45royale.com/wp-content/themes/45v6_sandbox/images/work/img_dww.jpg

http://www.45royale.com/wp-content/themes/45v6_sandbox/images/work/img_dww_hovered.jpg

Comment: works great, my bad.  i looked for the code for like an hour and couldnt find it.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could stick with one image and get same effect by either:

1. Going from [greyscale to colour](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/html5-grayscale-image-hover) with html5 canvas and jQuery (doesnt work in ie8).
2. Just turn down opacity and overlay an html caption with something like:

   ```
   $("div.casestudy").hover(function() {
   $(this).find('caption').fadeIn(200);
   $(this).find('img.hovered').animate({"opacity": "0.3"}, "slow");
   }, function() {
   $(this).find('caption').fadeOut(200);
   $(this).find('img.hovered').animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
   });
   ```

or something like that anyway